# Monaco Editor different themes on multiple editors on the same page?

Tags: monaco-editor

Can we set different themes on different editors on the same page? Or is it a global theme?

I tried monaco.editor.setTheme('vs') in the console and it changed all the editor themes.

I tried to set different themes in the configuration, but they still look the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I know, the question is quite old, but I have the same problem.
After some research I found this [Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/338) on GitHub. According to the developer of monaco, this is a feature and not a bug ;) So the feature-request is still open, but they don't plan to implement it.
This is unfortunately a KO criteria for the monaco-editor in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the theme for a particular editor using css.
In this way you can have different themes on multiple editors.

Here is a example of changing the editor background when focused:

```
.monaco-editor.focused {
  --vscode-editor-background: #000000;
}
```

You can take this further by assigning a class to specific editor, then using CSS to assign the theme:

```
.myclass .monaco-editor.focused {
  --vscode-editor-background: #000000;
}
```

Theme colours are here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Just modify the nameing for CSS (e.g. `editor.background` => `--vscode-editor-background`)